# Defining a protected method of custom return type within a derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, struct, protected

Using C++ and trying to write a method which returns an entity of type `thing` which is defined as protected in its parent class but getting the following error:

`'thing' does not name a type`

```
class A {
protected:
    struct thing{

    };
};

class B : public A {
    thing getThing();
};

thing B::getThing(){ // Error occurs on this line
    return new thing;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `B::thing B::getThing() {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here.

First, you must qualify`thing` as being within the namespace `A`.

```
A::thing B::getThing(){ // Error occurs on this line
    return new thing;
}
```

Also, `new thing` is going to return a `thing*`, which isn't implicitly convertible to a `thing`, so you need to either return `A::thing*` or `return thing()`.

Comment: By the way, the namespace isn't required with a trailing return type: `auto B::getThing() -> thing*`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `A::` in front of your return type on `getThing`:

```
A::thing B::getThing(){
    return thing();
}
```

`thing` was declaring inside `A`'s namespace, so you need to specify `A` when not already in that namespace.  Still, you code won't compile because you declared `getThing` as returning a `thing` but right now it returns a `thing *`.  You need to either change it to `return thing()` or change the declaration to return a `thing *`.